# jquery prop doesn't disabled after clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about jquery prop. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/vGKzPv)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are two edit button with id. When i click the first edit button then it is working fine. but The edit button working also second click i want to disable current clicked button. What i am missing here anyone can help me in this regard ?

js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#ser' + ID).prop('disabled', 'true');
      var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html();
      var editMarkUp = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea><button name="ok">Save</button><button name="cancel">Cancel</button>';
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editMarkUp);
   });
});
```

html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
      <div class="postInfo">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsa
      </div>
      <button class="editBtn" name="edit" id="ser1">Edit</button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB2">
      <div class="postInfo">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsass
      </div>
      <button class="editBtn" name="edit" id="ser2">Edit</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not targeting the `button`. Use `$(this).prop()`

```
$(this).prop('disabled', 'true');
```

OR

A javascript way of doing what you want would be to expose the `event` object and set the `disabled` property of `event.target`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = true;

      ...
   });
});
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVOQeO)

Comment: i just one question how to focus current clicked textarea. like `$(this).find('textarea').focus();` I have tried this way but it doesn't focused. If you have a time can you answer this question for me please ?

Comment: Add `$('#txtmessage_' + ID).focus();` at the end the method. The `find` method searches all descendants and `this` in your context is the edit button, which doesn't have any children.

Comment: thank you dear. I have used this think. `var data = $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val(); $('#txtmessage_' + ID).focus(); $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val(data + ' ');` with focus and End of Text.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this selector  `$('.editBtn' + ID).prop('disabled', 'true')` you don't have any button with `editBtn1 or editBtn2 class` so I used only `id selector`,
 check **snippet** below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function() {
     var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    
     $('#' + ID).prop('disabled', 'true');
     var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html();
     var editMarkUp = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea><button name="ok">Save</button><button name="cancel">Cancel</button>';
     $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editMarkUp);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
    <div class="postInfo">
      fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsa
    </div>
    <button class="editBtn" name="edit" id="1">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="postAr" id="messageB2">
    <div class="postInfo">
      fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsass
    </div>
    <button class="editBtn" name="edit" id="2">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```